# SQL Azure cannot connect to database with Polish collate

Tags: sql, azure, collation

Since Microsoft released new SDK for Windows Azure (June 2012) i have problem with connect to SQL Azure database with collation set to 'Polish_CI_AS'.

With previous sdk it works fine. Now when i want to add new connection string i have error:

"Unable to add data connection. Failed to retrieve data for this request. Unknown property PrimaryFilePath"

With default collation (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) connection string is creating.

Did anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to SQL Azure in Server Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979427/connecting-to-sql-azure-in-server-explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem and solution is described here in this blog [Working With Collations In SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/06/11/10023650.aspx)

The default collation for character data in SQL Azure databases is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. This collation is also used across the SQL Azure infrastructure to sort and compare metadata that defines database objects. The server and database level collations are not configurable in SQL Azure. However, you can use a collation of your choice at the column and expression level.

Comment: Thanks, it's weird that earlier everything worked. Unfortunately i can't change database collation so i have to create a new one, but thanks for help.

Comment: Thanks us3r!! Creating new sure will work and while creating you can follow the guidance provide by the SQL Azure team.

Comment: Perhaps this is the same as the problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216003/azure-nodejs-site-cannot-connect-to-sql-db-that-has-a-collation-different-than-t). No matter what, a connection to a non standard collation DB will not work