# Connecting to SQL Azure in Server Explorer returns error "unknown property PrimaryFilePath"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure-sql-database

When adding a new data connection in Server Explorer in VS 2010 (with Azure SDK),
I can successfully "Test Connection" but when adding it I get this alert box:

```
Unable to add data connection.
Failed to retrieve data for this request.
unknown property PrimaryFilePath
```

(Azure SQL server, i.e. xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net)

Anyone experienced this before?

Thanks!

**Edit: It seems to have to do with collation...**

...When using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS it works fine but the following does not work:

- Finnish_Swedish_CS_AS
- Finnish_Swedish_100_CI_AS
- Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default collation for character data in SQL Azure databases is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. The server and database level collations are not configurable in SQL Azure. **However, you can use a collation of your choice at the column and expression level.**

I believe your problem is described here in this blog: [Working With Collations In SQL Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-collations-in-sql-azure/).

This blog article will show you how.

Comment: Ok, I guess this looks like a semi-possible work around. But really, I doubt that this is still not supported 2012. Why can I choose a Server/DB collation in SQL Azure Manager on the web if it cannot be used? If it really wasn't supported (as said in the blog post), Microsoft wouldn't give me the choice... I'd guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue using SSDT for VS 2015. I changed the data provider to ".NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB" on the Change data Source window and it worked.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've got the error "unknown property PrimaryFilePath" when tried to connect to Azure DB from VS 2015, but succeeded when  connected   **from VS 2019**.