# "Unknown property PrimaryFilePath" error when connecting to Azure SQL Data Warehouse database

Tags: entity-framework, parallel-data-warehouse, azure-sql-server

I've tried to make a new data Connection From Microsoft Visual Studio  Entity Framework Data Model Wizard  to Azure SQL Data Warehouse , but got an error:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request. unknown property
>   PrimaryFilePath

I can successfully "Test Connection".
I also can create connection to Master database, but not to one, created by me.

Question [Connecting to SQL Azure in Server Explorer returns error "unknown property PrimaryFilePath"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979427/connecting-to-sql-azure-in-server-explorer) blames mismatched collations,
but

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation')   SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDataBase' , 'Collation')
```

returns SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS for both server and database.

As a workaround ( suggested on the [Microsoft Forums thread failed-to-retrieve-data-for-this-request-unknown-property-primaryfilepath](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d47e5d3-0c99-4568-883a-0a8515b256dc/failed-to-retrieve-data-for-this-request-unknown-property-primaryfilepath-error-when-create-new?forum=vsprereleaseannouncements)
 ) I re-created tables from the Azure SQL Data Warehouse on a local SQL Server and after more development will try to reconnect the  Entity Framework Data Model to  Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Is any better way to create data connection to Azure SQL Data Warehouse and avoid 'unknown property PrimaryFilePath' error?

What actually "property PrimaryFilePath" mean and can I specify it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Currently as of today EF is not supported on ASDW
See this Azure Feedback entry - and please feel free to VOTE UP !
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/12868725-support-for-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in VS 2015 and could not do much.
So I used VS 2017 and it worked well.